# css, after changed the width, the layout changed

Tags: css

I am learning CSS for building web app, and I changed the `width` from 100% to 60%, the layout changed

The code is from https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_forms

and the code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>

<div>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And The original output is Mobile style, not PC style

[image]

How can I change the `width` to 60% and keep the original layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change the `width` of the first `div` to `60%`. I added a new ID to prevent to set all `div` `width` to `60%`.

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

#newId {
    width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>

<div id="newId">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your form inside another container (See the "div.smaller") :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    input[type=text], select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }
    
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
    }
    
    div {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .smaller
    {
     width:60%;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    
    <h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>
    
    <div>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="smaller">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
    
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
    
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <select id="country" name="country">
          <option value="australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width you are looking to change is within the  tag.  If you change the width here, it will change the overall width of the  object, and leave the contained layout as you would expect.

```
div {
width: 60%;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the width of the div which have the form inside it.
and make the input width 100%. so automatically it will set to 60%.
Here your code is not working because by default your div width is 100% and you are trying to reduce the width of input box to 60%. So it reduced to 60% as respect to your div but not screen, so it all the other elements of div rearranged themselves in that way, to fill the gap.

try this code

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <style>
 .anotherClass{
 width:60%;
 }
input[type=text], select {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12px 20px;
 margin: 8px 0;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-sizing: border-box;

  }

 input[type=submit] {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 20px;
 margin: 8px 0;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
  }

  input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
   }

  div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
   }
 </style>
<body>

  <h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>

  <div class="anotherClass">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

 <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your lastname..">

<label for="country">Country</label>
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
 </select>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude just put the br element after every element: This is another very simple solution

Try this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <style>

 input[type=text],select {
width: 60%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

```
 input[type=submit] {
width: 60%;
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 input[type=submit]:hover {
background-color: #45a049;
 }

 div {
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 20px;
 }
 </style>
<body>

 <h3>Using CSS to style an HTML Form</h3>

<div>
 <form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="fname">First Name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.."><br>   

<label for="lname">Last Name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
 <br>

<label for="country">Country</label><br>
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That's a really bad solution.